# Drawing a shadow on CCLabelTTF

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, core-graphics

I am drawing a shadow on a CCLableTTF using CGContextSetShadowWithColor. I have set the colour to be white but i always get a grey/black line around the edge of the shadow.

Is there anyway to remove the outline, i have looked but i cannot see any stroke colour for the shadow.

Thanks

Comment: Check out https://github.com/jandrad/CCLabelFX for an easier way to do the shadows.

Comment: I am using CCLabelFX but the code that draws the shadow adds the stroke colour as well. Thanks